# Why can't the super constructor be invoked from an enum constructor?

Tags: java, reflection, enumeration, superclass

```
public enum A {
     A(1);

     private A(int i){
     }

     private A(){
         super(); // compile - error
             // Cannot invoke super constructor from enum constructor A()
     }

}
```

and here is the hierarchy of `enum A` extends from `abstract java.lang.Enum` extends `java.lang.Object`

```
Class c = Class.forName("/*path*/.A");
System.out.println(c.getSuperclass().getName());
System.out.println(Modifier.toString(c.getSuperclass().getModifiers()).contains("abstract"));
System.out.println(c.getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getName());
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enums imply a lot of magic at the compiler and runtime level to guaranty that == comparisons will always work:

> It is a compile-time error to attempt to explicitly instantiate an enum type (§15.9.1). The final clone method in Enum ensures that enum constants can never be cloned, and the special treatment by the serialization mechanism ensures that duplicate instances are never created as a result of deserialization. Reflective instantiation of enum types is prohibited. Together, these four things ensure that no instances of an enum type exist beyond those defined by the enum constants.

[Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.9) section 8.9

There is no parameterless Enum() constructor, only Enum(String name, int ordinal). But allowing to call that one with wrong parameters would obviously cause trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Let's look at this example. abstract class A; and class B extends A { private B(){super()}} . You can do that but not in enum. why ? A also hasn't any constructor but super() added to it at runtime. why not for enum ?

Comment: If there is no constructor, Java will create one without parameters. If you add a constructor A(String bla), the parameterless super() will not work anymore. Enum are really special, there is a lot of hidden magic going on. The compiler/runtime inserts a call to super(name, index). And is is crucial that this call is done with the right parameters, so the compiler has a special case which prevents manually calling the super constructor. In other words: The internals of enums are a big dirty hack.

Answer (score 7):

From the [Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) on Enums:

> All enums implicitly extend
>   java.lang.Enum. Since Java does not
>   support multiple inheritance, an enum
>   cannot extend anything else.

You can't invoke the `super()` constructor because the compiler automatically inserts a hidden call to `super(name, ordinal)` into any constructor you define.

Comment: thanks for your comment. class A don't extends from any other class. just want to call super() to see it's inheritance hierarchy tree. A->java.lang.Enum->java.lang.Object So I have a right call super() to java.lang.Enum and then super() to java.lang.Object

Comment: enums are "special". You have a "right" to call `super` on ordinary classes, but enums have more restrictions.

Comment: and my question is that, why ?

Comment: why not? Why add additional complexity to the language when it is not required? Perhaps you should give us a valid use case for wanting to do this.

Comment: I mean, it is contrary to the OO philosophy. being an object without being(calling) object? i think enum has no any special reason look at this. asbtract class A{}; class B extends A { private B() { super(); }} so it is also useless here but it is legal. I think there is different logic behind it or they(java core developers) just  hang around to code it

Comment: You don't seem to be aware that the cmpiler inserts a super() call itself. This is nothing to do with 'OO philosophy'.

Answer (score 1):

It is a fact that you cannot declare an `enum` as extending another class.  Therefore, there is only one possible `super` constructor for an `enum`.

I guess, since since you can't chain to anything other than `super()` they decided that it wasn't worth allowing the use of `super` at all in an `enum` constructor.

Either way, you are not losing anything.

Comment: I think, the init. of a object is finished when super()->super()->super()->Object reaches Object. So, how it can be initialize without calling super() so never reaches Object so how it can be extended from java.lang.Object

Comment: Huh??? I didn't say a super constructor wasn't called.  I only said there can only possibly be one such super constructor, therefore the `super()` *syntax* would be redundant.  (I presume that you understand what happens in a normal constructor when you leave out the `super` call ...)

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no super() constructor, see dogbane's answer, and because the compiler automatically inserts the super(...) call that is required, ditto.

Why is this a problem?

Comment: I think its a problem, because of coding standard/style to use super in constructors. its called standard, because it doesnt have to make sens.

Comment: @01: If your coding standard is telling youi to call superclass constructors that don't exist then there is something severely wrong with it. More likely you have misunderstood the requirement. You have to call super(x,y,...) for some x,y,... that do exist as constructor arguments.